# DOJO dropdown and datetextbox suddenly stop working after opening/closing dialog form a few times

Tags: dojo, ibm-content-navigator

I'm using dojo 1.9 inside Ibm Content Navigator and my dropdowns(dijit.form.DropDownButton) suddenly stop working after opening and closing the same screen about 15-20x. I click on the arrow and the options are not displayed. That happens with DateTextBox(dijit/form/DateTextBox) as well. And not only my screen dropdowns stop work but every single dropdown and DateTextBox in the system dont work anymore. All the other widgets are working fine. I have to refresh the page to make everything work again. Not doing anything special here.
these are 2 examples of dropdown and datetextbox
Does anyone have a clue of what is happening here ?

```
           <div
                data-dojo-attach-point="invoiceDateMisc" 
                data-dojo-attach-event="onChange: setCAVATCodes"
               name="${id}_invoiceDateMisc" id="${id}_invoiceDateMisc" 
                tabindex="13" 
                data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox"
                constraints="{ min: '01/01/1950',      max: new Date()}" 
                missingMessage="Invoice Date is a required field."
                rangeMessage="Invoice Date must not be a future date."
                required="true" > 

            </div>

            <div  data-dojo-attach-point="dbCrMisc" 
                    name="${id}_dbCrMisc" 
                    id="${id}_dbCrMisc" 
                    data-dojo-type="ecm.widget.Select"  
                    tabindex="14" >
             </div>
```

Comment: Looks like clean DoJo to me, the only reason i can think of is that you might have a collision on the ID if you do not clean up previous instances and happen to use the same id. - any stacktraces in the console?

Comment: @IvoJonker check my answer below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there were some no modal dialogs where I show error/warning messages to users that were not being properly closed, just hidden, so after some time of system usage, it breaks the dropdowns and calendars for some unknow reason. Really tought one, no error messages, nothing on console, not a clue and I still dont know why it happened. And my attempt to fix this was just a guess, a feeling, knowing a bit more of Dojo behavior.